# iGoogle style dashboard using jquery

Tags: jquery-plugins

Is there any jquery plugin for implementing iGoogle style dashboard? So basically drag n drop style etc.

Thanks

---

I recently found this:

http://www.webappers.com/2008/11/19/how-to-create-igoogle-interface-with-jquery/

Hope that helps...

Comment: Refer my blog [Creating a webpage like iGoogle using jQuery](http://sweettam.blogspot.com/2011/02/creating-webpage-like-igoogle-using.html)

Comment: Correct link is http://sweettam.blogspot.com/2011/02/creating-webpage-like-igoogle-using.html

Comment: You can also check it out
http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/index.php

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Take a look at [the jQuery UI portlet demo for Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#portlets).

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking for a similar dashboard framework, please check out my implementation of igoogle style dashboard called 'sDashboard' : http://modeln.github.com/sDashboard/

This plugin, helps in converting an array of widget definitions into a dashboard, were each object in the array gets rendered as a dashboard widget.

Its has some neat features to render table and charting widgets and is highly configurable. The documentation page includes a link to a demo application & example usages to render different styled widgets.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [my implementation of an iGoogle style Dashboard using jQuery](http://civicrm.org/node/677).

Comment: this is free? can I use it in a commercial software?

Comment: It's licensed under GNU AGPL 3

Comment: So no. It can't be (without paying)

Comment: Anthony Mills answer as 14 votes and this answer one vote.  You should change the accepted answer.

Comment: Note that my implementation uses jQuery UI sortable portlets